# How to validate Username in Login activity

Tags: java, android, validation, authentication

I'm very new to this Android, so I'm very sorry if this question will make you laugh.

Recently I'm trying an Android tutorial about 'Creating Login Screen With SQLite'. I'm successfully creating that Login along with Register and with SQLite DB. What I want to know is how to change the Text Input from Email to Username.

I have searched the code for how to changing the validation from Email to Username but still don't get that.

FYI, I have created the Username table in the DB.

```
public boolean validate() {
    boolean valid = false;

    // Get values from EditText fields
    String Email = editTextUsername.getText().toString();
    String Password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

    // Handling validation for Email Address
    if (!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(Email).matches()){
        valid = false;
        textInputLayoutUsername.setError("Input Correct Username");
    } else {
        valid = true;
        textInputLayoutUsername.setError(null);
    }
}
```

Here is my login screen.

[image]

I had to change the text from Email to Username on that `EditText`. But when I run it, the `EditText` always validate the email. I think there's something to change in this line.

```
!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(Email).matches()
```

Thanks before for all the help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Minor point: the name of the platform/operating system is Android. Android Studio is just the tool that you use to write Android software.

Comment: I am confused about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Don't worry, it is fine to have questions. The important thing is to ask the question properly so that others can help. Welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Your current implementation is validating the input from the `editTextUsername` and trying to validate if the input is a valid email address. If you do not want that, just remove the validation for this specific view in your code like the following.

```
public boolean validate() {
    boolean valid = false;

    //Get values from EditText fields
    String userName = editTextUsername.getText().toString();
    String Password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

    // Handle the validation for the user name. 
    // Let us assume, you just want to validate that the user has put something as a user name
    if(userName.length() > 0) {
        valid = true;
        textInputLayoutUsername.setError(null);
    } else {
        valid = false;
        textInputLayoutUsername.setError("Please provide the user name.");
    }
}
```

You can always change the logic of your validation. I just showed an example. I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just use plain text field and use regular express in backend code ( [A-Za-z0-9]* ) to validate your input.

```
//it's saying if email contains alpnum char and ._- of length min 3 i.e >=3 then its true
if(Email.matches(^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]{3,}$)) {
   // valid input code
} else {
  // invalid input code
}
```

Comment: can you teach me that syntax sir ? 

*edit
I found that, thanks sirr

Answer (score 0):

please check the blow code.

public boolean validate() {

```
    //Get values from EditText fields
    String userName = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
    String Password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();


    if (userName.isEmpty()) {

        //set error message 
        return  false;
    } else if (Password.isEmpty()) {
        //set error message 
        return  false;
    } else if (Password.length()<6 || Password.length()>15) {
        // set error message
        return  false;
    }

    return  true;

}
```